# What is the database model of Apache HAWQ?

Tags: database-design

I read a lot of blogs about hawq and how it is adapted from Pivotal Greenplum.
[Hortonworks](https://hortonworks.com/apache/hawq/) say, it is native sql engine over hadoop.
Pivotal say, it is a SQL query database that combines powers of Greenplum + Hadoop. It also supports OLAP.

**Now I know there are databases and database models.**

> **Which database model best describes HAWQ ?**

1. Relational
2. Wide column
3. Document
4. Hybrid
5. Something else ?

Please help!